# ReactRouter route render component to container element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

My issue here is that I need to render separate route components to elements created by the backend.  It's irregular I'm sure.  Essentially I'm starting with an html document and need to render route components to particular elements in the dom.

Example:

If I have four components that each need to be rendered to a pre-generated element.

```html
<body>
<div id="elone" />
<div id="eltwo" />
<div id="elthree" />
<div id="elfour" />
</body>
```

Now I need to render my respective components to each of those elements.  The issue is that if I call ReactDOM.render within the component it doesn't recognize the router, and it doesn't appear that route has anyway to render to a particular element.

Note:  I cannot unfortunately write the document within the JS, it has to be pre-generated.  I don't need this to be done through react router if there are other solutions, but the components must recognize the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, it makes it seem like no one is really answering questions here.

Anyhow the solution is to use ReactDOM.createPortal instead of ReactDOM.render within the components.  Make sure to render the component with the router to an element outside of the container that you want to portal your subcomponents to otherwise you'll obviously clobber the elements that your portals are pointing to.